# Apache as proxy with "catch-all"

Tags: apache, proxy

I want to have Apache proxy to different servers and also have a "catch everything else that doesn't fit" to a server.

I want the following cases where ProxyPass is configured in the proxy's Apache conf file:

- ProxyPass / - The "catch-all" where everything else that doesn't fit will go here
- ProxyPass /sub1 - going to /sub1 takes me to sub1.domain.com...
- ProxyPass /sub2 - going to /sub2 takes me to sub2.domain.com...

I tried the following:

```
<Location /sub1>
  ProxyPass http://sub1.domain.com/
</Location>

<Location /sub2>
  ProxyPass http://sub2.domain.com/
</Location>

<Location />
  ProxyPass http://sub1.domain.com/
</Location>
```

This doesn't seem to work as everything defaults to `<Location />`.

I tried using LocationMatch and wasn't successful in getting sub1 or sub2 to return content. Referred from here: https://serverfault.com/questions/591591/apache-locationmatch-regex-behaviour-does-not-seem-correct

With the above LocationMatch, the headers were working but no content was returned. Going to /A or /B resulted to "Not found".

Does anyone know how I can get this working for Apache or is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try proxypassmatch instead of location directive.